# Issue with ajax POST/GET method sending to a php file. keep getting error

Tags: php, ajax

I am currently trying to set up a request such that when a button is clicked, it runs uses ajax to call a php script to change stuff in the database. but I am having issues where I keep getting an error with the

this is the ajax request. anytime I run this. I get an error stating "Error 500 (internal server error)"

```
$.ajax({
            url:"./scripts/test.php", //the page containing php script
            type: "POST", //request type,
            data: {registration: "success"},
            success:function(result){
        
            console.log(result.abc);
            },
            error: function(req, textStatus, errorThrown) {
            alert('Ooops, something happened: ' + textStatus + ' ' +errorThrown);
            }
                 });
```

my php code:

```
<?php

echo "hello world";
?>
```

I dont know what could be causing this, but anytime I try this on my live website (or local) it doesnt want to work.

Comment: Remove the space between `<?` and `php` here `<? php`

Comment: @JayBlanchard I fixed it, but that shouldnt be the issue since It doesnt even successfully send anything to the php file

Comment: Yes it does, otherwise you wouldn't be getting a 500 error which is a server-side error.

Comment: Open the browser's developer tools (F12) and watch the request/response in the network tab of the developer tools when you trigger the AJAX call. Change `console.log(result.abc);` to `console.log(result);`

Comment: Holy shit, my bad for being so dismissive haha. you're right it was the space. I thought i fixed it before. but I forgot to send it to my live server. youre a godsend. thank you